# What is the "shoutOutCannedMessage" method?

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to do a homework assignment where the application asks the user to input 10 strings, then displays them all, and finally ask the user to select 1 to display a second time. For extra credit, I'm using a HashMap (named *shout*) to store the data instead of an ArrayList.

My professor wants me to output the 10 strings using the `shoutOutCannedMessage()` method.

**MY QUESTION: What is the**  `shoutOutCannedMessage()` **method and how do I use it in this situation?** Why can't I just do `System.out.println(shout);`, which worked completely fine when I tried it?

I cannot find anything online about this method in terms of a general description, cannot find it anywhere in our textbook, etc.

I tried `shoutOutCannedMessage(shout);` to no avail. I get the error message:

```
cannot find symbol

symbol: method shoutOutCannedMessage(HashMap<Integer,String>)

location: class ShoutBox
```

This is for an online class so we don't have lectures and it'd take 48 hours to get a response via email from the professor. I've been trying to watch thenewboston's video tutorials to guide me through this class and haven't found anything relevant to this assignment.

**SECOND QUESTION:** How do I then proceed to have a user select just one key from the HashMap to be displayed, using the  `shoutOutCannedMessage()` method?

Thank you very much to anybody who offers assistance!

EXACT ASSIGNMENT INSTRUCTIONS:

> You will create the ShoutBox class for your Virtual World. Your ShoutBox class will have a shoutOutCannedMessage() method that returns a String type. The shoutOutCannedMessage will use an Array or an ArrayList to store 10 messages of type String. For those of you that are more advanced with your Java skills, you could use a HashMap for the data structure. You can load this data structure with 10 messages of your choosing. For example, one message could be “I need Java!” You can initialize your Array or ArrayList with the messages or have the user enter the messages. The choice is yours. The shoutOutCannedMessage() will loop through the data structure to first display all canned messages and allow the user to select one. The shoutOutCannedMessage() will return the selected message String.

Comment: It seems like you have to define and implement `shoutOutCannedMessage()` in your class `ShoutBox`

Comment: Perhaps you should add the exact wording of the assignment to your question. It seems that method is either something you have to implement, or something that is in a library the professor was supposed to give you.

Comment: I think that's why I'm so confused: How (and where) do I define and implement something when I don't understand its purpose within the code?

Comment: Well, the problem statement gives the behavior and output in the last couple sentences: `"The shoutOutCannedMessage() will loop through the data structure to first display all canned messages and allow the user to select one. The shoutOutCannedMessage() will return the selected message String."`  If you don't understand what your teacher means by that, you need to ask them for clarification.  We can't really help you with requirements given by a third party.

Comment: @azurefrog

I was just originally oblivious to the fact that he wanted me to make the method. I thought this was some sort of commonly-used method already in existence that I just needed to make use of. 

The entire assignment IS the method. Now I get it thanks to all of you. I apologize for my blonde-ness.

Comment: Gathering requirements is as much of a learned skill as writing the code.  Nobody expects you to be an instant expert ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing a key concept in this lesson.  The instructor wants YOU to implement the shoutOutCannedMessage() method.  Of course you can't find it anywhere online, etc. because your professor made up the name for this method.  It is your homework to implement it and code the method.  It should be easy enough as you are using the HashMap so each time the user enters in a string it'll be put into the Hash.  Then just ask the user which one they want to repeat, by entering in an integer, and if you've coded things properly it will then output their selection.

Comment: I see; that does make sense. I was under the impression that `shoutOutCannedMessage()` was some predefined method that existed within the main library; given its similarity to `System.out.print`.

After re-reading the assignment instructions, it does seem like what you're saying is true. Does that mean I should just change the name of the HashMap to `shoutOutCannedMessage` instead of *shout*; as I've already done the HashMap and the while loop, as well as the iterating through the Hash through the use of the aforementioned `System.out.println(shout);`.

Thank you for the new perspective!

Comment: My friend, it seems there is a lot you are not understanding that your instructor has tried teaching you.  You should go to your instructor with your questions from here as the path that we are going down here I'll end up writing the entire code for you.
But, to answer you immediate question you should not rename the HashMap.  The HashMap and the method are two different things.  You should have a method called "shoutOutCannedMessage" and within that method you'll have a HashMap called whatever you'd like.